# Jquery Accordion :hover action does not trigger when a section has previously been opened

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I noticed an issue with my jquery accordion menu.

When I open a section and close it again the ':hover' functionality seems to stop working for that particular section. The ':hover' functionality still works on the other sections that I have not yet clicked.

If I click them all then ':hover' stops working for all of the sections.

I would be incredibly greatful for some assistance.

Many thanks

Robert

Here is a jsFiddle link to a quick sample of the code demonstrating the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/yUyEC/

hover the sections to see that the background positions are shifted. Click one section, then click another and hover the previous section. Something odd is happening :)

In this sample please note that the div slide positioning is off, It is fine in the main version, the issue is demonstrated well though.

Comment: Any chance you could make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example or link to the actual page?

Comment: Here is a small example with jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/yUyEC/

hover the sections to see that the background positions are shifted.
Click one section, then click another and hover the previous section.

Something odd is happening :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would make the code valid, e.g.

```
<div class="sidebar_game_header">
  <a href="http://www.apple.com/">
   <img src="http://robertmegone.com/jsfiddle/images/icn_1.png" alt="Game 4 Icon"/>
   <div class="sidebar_game_header_text">Game 4</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

You can't nest a block level `div` in an inline level `a` element, doing this will be causing the browsers to try error recovery to reconstruct the DOM and display the elements as you want, that's usually fine but as soon as you add interactivity via JS functions code/display is very likely to break.. not saying it is here but it's likely not helping ;)

then I'd say that positioning or floating is not necessary in this menu at all, it should be easy enough to get the image and text into the "header" using inline blocks. Then they shouldn't have a need to move (the quirky behaviour that's happening just now)

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but the CSS could be doing most of the work for you so that the jQuery just has to slide up and down the child menus and not have anything to do with the hovers which would work via the CSS as in a plain menu.. but anyway.. here's some fixed HTML/CSS code which sort of works with your jQuery

### JSFiddle: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/nY2EN/)

note IE7 is throwing an error, I don't know why, but I think the basics are there, I changed the nested `div` to a `span` and made it and the image vertically align using inline-block, the rest didn't need floated or positioned as that is there natural positions

if you want the links to be white you have to specify `a` too in the CSS `color` on the div is not enough to target link color..

think that's it for now

---

Ok I played around a bit more, I don't really understand the code you were using, but I just felt I needed to get the CSS out of the jQuery so your hover states would activate

I made an updated example, which someone could very likely optimise, this does everything I think; hover states, move backgrounds etc.. via CSS, and the only extra thing it does is to add a class to the "open" accordion header so it retains the same CSS as the hovered state

The last thing I'm not sure about is which of those links you would need to prevent the default behaviour on (header links?) - I just copped out and didn't make the `<span>` text a link at all ;)

I also changed the inner list to a list ;) it works the same

(btw IE7 is no longer throwing an exception with this code)

### New Example: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/PB53v/)

Comment: Fantastic answer, The div class sidebar_game_header objects are still not responding to :hover again after they have been selected and de-selected. 
On hover the elements should always do 'background-position:bottom;' unless they are already selected.

Though I am so grateful for your help.

Comment: Thanks, still practising my jQuery so I updated the answer with a solution that gets the hover states and adds a class to make the "selected" choice have the same CSS.. hope the logic helps.. sorry I didn't use the jQuery you had..